# Is there a way to show video in Dialogflow Messenger

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working on a [Dialogflow Messenger integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#showminchat) and Im trying to see if there is any way of showing a You Tube video as one of the responses. As far as I can see there are no Rich Response Messages which support video.
The only way which springs to mind is to listen for [df-response-received](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#df-response-received) events and then add the embed code on the fly which seems hideous.
Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I basically answered my own question here. I actually needed other UI elements so I built my own chat interface in React as a web component using [direflow.io](https://www.direflow.io) then I had full control over my UI :)
Any new components I want to display I can send as a [custom payload](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom) as normal